# multiple eyediagrams on a single figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, subplot

Is there a way to have multiple eyediagrams on a single figure in MATLAB. I want to do something like this:

```
figure;
subplot(311);
eyediagram(x1, ....);
subplot(312);<br>
eyediagram(x2, ....); 
subplot(313);
eyediagram(x3, ....);
```

Unfortunately each call to eyediagram creates its own plot. I already tried to plot multiple eyediagram and copy them individually to another figure but I was wondering if there is a better/cleaner way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/eyediagram.html):

> Note:   You cannot use hold on to plot multiple signals in the same figure.

Based on that statement, and the fact that you can *only* specify a figure handle to `eyediagram` (see below) and not an `axes` handle, this is not possible apart from manually copying the plot objects as you have stated (likely using `copyobj`).

**Specifying a Figure**

> eyediagram(x,n,period,offset,plotstring,h) is the same as the syntax above, except that the eye diagram is in the figure whose handle is h, rather than in a new figure. h must be a handle to a figure that eyediagram previously generated.